# Data not loading through SQLDataAdapter to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am new to ASP.NET and using below query to fetch data in SQLDataAdapter for GridView display. But it looks like the data is not fetching in SQLDataAdapter itself.The same code is working fine with SQLReader.
Can anyone help me to understand what am I doing wrong here?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        String sql = "Select top 100 * from xyz";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet Output = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(Output, "out");
        GridViewOutput.DataSource = Output.Tables["out"];

        /*  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
          {
              using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
              {
                  while (reader.Read())
                  {
                      Response.Write( reader.GetString(0)+ reader.GetString(2));
                  }
              }

          }*/

      conn.Close();
```

Comment: Try `GridViewOutput.DataSource = Output.Tables[0]`. I think `adapter.Fill(Output, "out")` makes no sense here because the second parameter is `IDataReader`, `adapter.Fill(Output)` should fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call -

> GridViewOutput.DataBind()

After specifying data source.

More on this -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You just missed line to bind the Gridview.

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        conn.Open();
    }

    String sql = "Select top 100 * from xyz";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataSet Output = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(Output, "out");
    GridViewOutput.DataSource = Output.Tables["out"];
    GridViewOutputData.DataBind();

    /*  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
      {
          using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
          {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                  Response.Write( reader.GetString(0)+ reader.GetString(2));
              }
          }

      }*/

  conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're forgot to include `DataBind()` method after setting data source. The proper way for `GridView` data binding should be like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet output = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(Output, "out");
GridViewOutput.DataSource = Output; // bind directly to DataSet
GridViewOutput.DataBind(); // bind to grid
```